# Lot of command line arguments for different classes

Tags: c#, parsing, design-patterns, command-line

We use specific software which execute my console application with lot of arguments (now it's 25(!) and may be more and more). And, of course, different arguments need for different classes. I parse it with NDesk.Options. But, I did it for all classes again and again.

```
class A {
    A (IEnumerable<String> args){
        new OptionSet {
            { "arg1=", value => foo1 = value },
                { "arg2=", value => foo2 = value },
            ...
        }.Parse(args);
    }
}
class B {
    B (IEnumerable<String> args){
        new OptionSet {
            { "arg10=", value => foo10 = value },
                { "arg11=", value => foo11 = value },
            ...
        }.Parse(args);
    }
}
```

How make this for good design? Parse all arguments in static class and use it or something else?

Comment: A "good design" is relative. One quality of your design could be maintainability. You can strive to make it easier to add new arguments (sounds like that is what's giving you trouble). You would then strive to isolate the elements to minimize the impact of those changes. What is the characteristic of your problem domain that makes the arguments so unstable?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, Logic is very simple, console app need to start some .exe files with this arguments. And every week it may need additional parameters (like now, I added 10 arguments). I against it, but my technical сhief adhere to such architecture...

Comment: If the arguments (requirements) change every week without some kind of reason you can identify, it will be hard to make a design that makes it easy. If you can identify an external force that's motivating these new arguments, you might be able to design for them to be more easily integrated. If you don't specify the details, it's hard for me to suggest more.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're asking for design patterns, this sounds like a job for the [Interpreter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern).

Otherwise, in my experience, command-line argument 'parsing' is a great case for **Pattern Matching**, which, unfortunately, C# doesn't have, but F# does. In [ZeroToNine](https://github.com/ploeh/ZeroToNine), the argument matching currently looks like this:

```
let Parse argv =
    match argv |> Seq.toList with
    | ["-l"] -> ListVersions
    | ["-a"; IsProperVersionString version] -> Assign version
    | ["-i"; "major"] -> Increment Rank.Major
    | ["-i"; "minor"] -> Increment Rank.Minor
    | ["-i"; "build"] -> Increment Rank.Build
    | ["-i"; "patch"] -> Increment Rank.Build
    | ["-i"; "revision"] -> Increment Rank.Revision
    | ["-a"; "major"; IntegerGreaterThanOrEqualToZero rankValue] -> AssignRank(Rank.Major, rankValue)
    | ["-a"; "minor"; IntegerGreaterThanOrEqualToZero rankValue] -> AssignRank(Rank.Minor, rankValue)
    | ["-a"; "build"; IntegerGreaterThanOrEqualToZero rankValue] -> AssignRank(Rank.Build, rankValue)
    | ["-a"; "patch"; IntegerGreaterThanOrEqualToZero rankValue] -> AssignRank(Rank.Build, rankValue)
    | ["-a"; "revision"; IntegerGreaterThanOrEqualToZero rankValue] -> AssignRank(Rank.Revision, rankValue)
    | ["-?"] -> ShowHelp
    | ["-h"] -> ShowHelp
    | [] -> ShowHelp
    | x -> Unknown(x)
    |> Seq.singleton
```

Granted, we don't have 25 different arguments, but the above example should still give you a good feel for how easy it is to handle various cases.

Even if you have a C# code base, you could write a parser library in F#.

On a slightly different note: if your console application takes 25 different arguments, would it make sense to split it up into several smaller console applications? It sounds like it's doing a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't Iterpreter be overdesign? Arguments usually aren't a syntactic language, and the example given by the OP looks very simple. I'm not sure [tag:design-patterns] always means Gang of Four design patterns (thank goodness).

Comment: How about two arguments? F.e. app.exe -i major -i minor

Comment: The List Pattern can match on more than two elements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx You can also nest pattern matching, or use [Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The [Builder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html) could be used to configure parsers and/or classes with the command-line arguments. This avoids having constructors that have a large number of arguments, some of which might be optional. It allows adding new arguments easily.

[Apache](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-cli2/manual/) has a good example of Builder used with Command-Line parsing.

On the other hand, Builder is risky. It's sometimes used to avoid the anti-pattern of a constructor with too many arguments. The reason that's an anti-pattern is because you're likely exposing too much of a classes secrets (implementation details), or equally bad, the class has too many responsibilities.

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, the fact that arguments are numerous and changing all the time might be a sign of a bad high-level design. It's hard to say without more details.